# Someone Shoot Me!

Tags: knowledge, situation, real

Real-life situation, this time.  I was at work the other day and had just done something.  I needed to tell a coworker he needed to do it as well, but he was on the phone at the time.

Not wanting to wait around til he was done nor interrupt his conversation, I got his attention and gestured.  First, I gestured the way I had came, then I formed my right hand into a gun pointing directly at my forehead and mimed pulling the trigger.  My coworker nodded, finished up his phone call, and went to get it taken care of.

I wasn't telling him to get himself killed, so ***what was I telling my coworker to do?***

Comment: To assassinate your much hated Boss

Comment: Metaphorically killing his dignity by continuing to wage-slave in a toxic, underpaid work environment with too much required overtime, and starting with that by stopping to talk to his friend at the phone?

Comment: Sorry, but I also have to point out the obvious nsfw answer, you can think of it yourself: 'The way he had came' + 'shot'........

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> To get his temperature tested by a temperature gun for Covid 19?

Comment: Truly, we're living in the future

Comment: I can't help feeling that's extremely dangerous and open to interpretation. Your comment on the question could easily have been the results. Actually, maybe that's what actually happened and OP is looking for a defence?  (/s just in case)

Answer (score 6):

If you flapped your arms to gesture that you
$\underline{\quad A\quad}$ in
and indicated that you got
$\underline{\quad B\quad}$ . . .

> $~~~A~~$ = “flew” $~\to~\,$
>     $A'$  = “flu” 
>  $~~~B~~$ = “shot” 
>  $A' ~ B$ = “flu shot”

. . . . then you reminded your coworker to get their annual company-sponsored
$\underline{\quad A' ~ B\quad}$.